# How to configure Shutdown tasks?

Tags: scripts, tmpfs

I have a shell script I'd like to run automatically every time I logout, shutdown or reboot.

Does anyone know where can I configure this in Ubuntu 10.10?

Answer (score 4):

> To execute a script at startup of Ubuntu

- Edit `/etc/rc.local` and add your commands.
- The script must always end with `exit 0`

> To execute a script upon rebooting Ubuntu

- Put your script in `/etc/rc0.d`
- And make it executable (`sudo chmod +x script`)
- Note that scripts in this directory are executed in alphabetical order.
- The name of your script must begin with K99 to run at the right time.

> To execute a script at shutdown

- Put your script in `/etc/rc6.d`
- and make it executable (`sudo chmod +x script`)
- Note that scripts in this directory are executed in alphabetical order.
- The name of your script must begin with K99 to run at the right time.

> To execute a script on logout

- `man bash` has this to say about it: `When  a  login  shell  exits, bash reads and executes commands from the file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists`. So you can add script executed during logout to `~/.bash_logout`.
- Do make sure it is executable.
- You might need to add `$HOME/.bash_logout` to `etc/gdm/PostSession/Default` for it to work.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 12.04, and directory `/etc/gdm` doesn't exist. Where else I can put the script such that it executes on logout as well as shutdown?

Comment: @Rinzwind..I am trying to do the same described above but am failing to do so.Please help me out.Have put my question on stackoverflow.:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674103/thin-server-auto-restart-script

Answer (score -1):

It is very simple.  Go to "System" and then to "start up applications" (i am not with a english verision - but you wil remark it what i mean). Press on the button "add" and simlply fill the necessary things.

If you want only to run at shutdown: make a script with de shutdown command into it, but before this command line execute your task you want to do.
To shutdown / poweroff Ubuntu Linux

sudo halt
or
sudo shutdown -h now
To reboot Ubuntu Linux
sudo reboot

Shutdown command can only be executed by the root.  Change the shutdown command wrigths, this is the most simply way..

Comment: what about shutdown/reboot tasks?